# tkinter tic tac toe board not formatted correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

There is spacing around the tic-tac-toe board that I don't know how to fix. If I remove all labels it fixes. For reference, this is a project for school and I'm unable to use any other config and grid options.

```
def button(window,row,column):
    button=tkinter.Button(window)
    #confiC3details
    button.config(text='')
    button.config(font=['comic sans ms',20])
    button.config(bg='#ffffff')
    button.config(width=5)

    button.grid(row=row)
    button.grid(column=column)
def createGameBoard(window):
def playTicTacToe():
    window=createWindow()

    title=createTitle(window)
  #  player1label=createPlayer1Label(window)
    # Create the components for the game
    
    

    # Setup the commands for all the different buttons
    button(window,1,1)
    button(window,1,2)
    button(window,1,3)
    button(window,2,1)
    button(window,2,2)
    button(window,2,3)
    button(window,3,1)
    button(window,3,2)
    button(window,3,3)

    # Start the game

    window.mainloop()
# =============================================================
#Start the tic-tac-toe game
playTicTacToe()
```

I tried padx and pady but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The code you provided will not run as-written.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my example.

```
import tkinter as tk  
  
root = tk.Tk()  
b1=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b1.grid(row=1,column=1)
b2=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b2.grid(row=1,column=2)
b3=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b3.grid(row=1,column=3)
b4=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b4.grid(row=2,column=1)
b5=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b5.grid(row=2,column=2)
b6=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b6.grid(row=2,column=3)
b7=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b7.grid(row=3,column=1)
b8=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b8.grid(row=3,column=2)
b9=tk.Button(root,width=20,height=10)
b9.grid(row=3,column=3)
   
root.mainloop()
```